# empty sqlite file after building

Tags: c#, sqlite

I'm trying to write a C# console application that interacts with a sqlite DataBase. Every time I try to build my console application project, an empty SuperCrewNet.sqlite file is being created in my Bin folder and causes the "Flights" table (and all other tables) to disappear, the original sqlite file next to the main cs file id perfectly fine.
When I try to the sqlite_cmd.ExecuteScalar(), an exeption is thrown (no such table: Flights)

How do I solve this problem??

```
sqlite_conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=SuperCrewNet.sqlite;Version=3;New=True;Compress=True;");
        sqlite_conn.Open();
        sqlite_cmd = sqlite_conn.CreateCommand();
        sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "SELECT FlightID FROM Flights WHERE FlightID='" + FlightNumber + FlightDate + "'";

        sqliteDatareader = sqlite_cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: The `New=True` in the connection string looks like it's forcing the creation of a new database. Try removing that.

Answer (score 0):

Check this site for help on connection strings:

http://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlite/

As mentioned in comments:

> **Create a new database:**
>
> ```
> Data Source=c:\mydb.db;Version=3;New=True;
> ```

So just remove `New=True;`

Comment: I tried using the basic connection string and it appears that the sqlite file is not being created each time now :-)  however....I get now a different error "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt" it seems like i went a step backwards....any ideas anyone?